# App Crashes! (Log attached)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, crash

This is a part of Crash Log sent by the tester and I see the crash here but good thing is I have no idea what to fix in my code.

I have saved the app.dSYM files necessary for displaying symbolic information (as per Apple's guidance) but I still don't see any relevant information.

Any help?

```
Incident Identifier: 45E8DE25-A6A6-4DA6-9F8D-E0D3248C5F67
CrashReporter Key:   d748fabd4ec0c36d7d5610b9a504e9bbc1900fde
Process:         MyApp [509]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2F63C765-0597-4AEF-B787-7FADBACACE6F/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2009-09-10 15:28:02.967 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd594c __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd593a kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd592e raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31deccf8 abort + 36
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ef840 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 588
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300166b8 _objc_terminate + 160
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ecf34 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ecfac std::terminate() + 16
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ed0d4 __cxa_throw + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300165dc objc_exception_throw + 92
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3022b622 -[NSException raise] + 2
11  Foundation                      0x30584bf6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 162
12  Foundation                      0x3050c198 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 194
13  Foundation                      0x3050be10 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 92
14  MyApp                           0x00019c2e 0x1000 + 101422
15  MyApp                           0x00019b22 0x1000 + 101154
16  MyApp                           0x00003a6a 0x1000 + 10858
17  UIKit                           0x308f159c -[UIApplication _performInitializationWithURL:sourceBundleID:] + 540
18  UIKit                           0x308f1174 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:sourceBundleID:] + 576
19  UIKit                           0x309374a8 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1512
20  UIKit                           0x30936ce8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 60
21  UIKit                           0x30936874 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 4336
22  GraphicsServices                0x32046964 PurpleEventCallback + 1028
23  CoreFoundation                  0x30254a70 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2296
24  CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
25  UIKit                           0x308f034c -[UIApplication _run] + 512
26  UIKit                           0x308eea8c UIApplicationMain + 960
27  MyApp                           0x00002090 0x1000 + 4240
28  MyApp                           0x0000202c 0x1000 + 4140
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in your MyApp that you are trying to get the value for a key that does not exist. Check that the object (NSObject) you have actually has the key for what you are trying to get the value of.

Comment: Also, use the debugger to step through your code to find out exactly where and when it is crashing.

Comment: I have rechecked and everything looks fine. Also, the app never crashes on my ipod (I used debugger as well).

Comment: Is there any way to look what MyApp is doing on the line No. 14, 15 and 16. It shows nothing except some hex values. Can I see some symbolic information here like a class/ method name etc.

Comment: You can if you compile it with debugging symbols.

In addition what has already previously said: when it doesn't find the key, an exception  is raised and it doesn't look like you catch the exception.

Comment: Can you please help me with how to "compile it with debugging symbols"?

P.S. I have the crash log and .dSYM files (and source code as well).